# I slept Vs. I was sleeping

Tags: grammar, past-simple, past-continuous

> She was so tired that she **slept** for several hours.
> She was so tired that she **was sleeping** for several hours.

Do both are correct? My teacher says that the first is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> (1) She was so tired that she slept for several hours.

(1) is perfectly natural and is the most common way to express this thought.

> (2) She was so tired that she was sleeping for several hours.

I would not day that (2) was **wrong**, but it is an unusual way to express this. **Unless** some other event ovvurs during this time. for example:

> - (2A) She was so tired that she was sleeping for several hours. During that time he prepared a meal and steadied his nerves.
> - (2B) She was so tired that she was sleeping for several hours while he prepared a meal and steadied his nerves.

Even in these cases "slept" could well be used instead of "was sleeping". More cpommoin uses of "sleeping" might be something such as:

> - (3A) She was sleeping when the telephone rang.
> - (3B) She had been sleeping for several hours when the telephone rang.
> - (2C)  She was so tired that, while she was sleeping, he spent several hours preparing a meal and steadying his nerves.
> - (4) She was so tires that she had been sleeping for several hours before she stirred.

All of these seem quite natural to me. But in 2C "slept" could still be used in place of "was sleeping" , and in all of 2C, 3A, 3B, and 4 "asleep" could be used in placve of "sleeping".